# VisualBasic How to Send Base64

Tags: vb.net, base64, mailmessage

Right I am stumped as hell and I don't even know what I am doing is right. I have some Base64 code of an image which I am emailing using Visual Basic (codes below) but when I recive the email its just shows the box and red cross.

My knowlage is very slim on this and I have just hacked this together. I could be doing something fundamentily stupid but I would not be aware of it.

Please advise :S

*VB Code*

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim mySmtpClient As SmtpClient
    Dim myMessage As MailMessage
    Dim FileReader As StreamReader
    Dim EmailBody As String

    FileReader = New StreamReader("D:\Extracts\Body.html")

    EmailBody = FileReader.ReadToEnd()

    myMessage = New MailMessage("eg@example.com", "eg@example.com")
    myMessage.Body = EmailBody
    myMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
    mySmtpClient = New SmtpClient("Server")
    mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
    mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

*Body.html*

```
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAABVAAD/4QNtaHR0cDov
    L25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLwA8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENl
    aGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/PiA8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIiB4
    OnhtcHRrPSJBZG9iZSBYTVAgQ29yZSA1LjAtYzA2MCA2MS4xMzQ3NzcsIDIwMTAvMDIvMTItMTc6
    MzI6MDAgICAgICAgICI+IDxyZGY6UkRGIHhtbG5zOnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5
    OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyI+IDxyZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24gcmRmOmFib3V0PSIiIHht
    bG5zOnhtcE1NPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvbW0vIiB4bWxuczpzdFJlZj0i
    aHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL3NUeXBlL1Jlc291cmNlUmVmIyIgeG1sbnM6eG1w
    PSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bXBNTTpPcmlnaW5hbERvY3VtZW50SUQ9
    InhtcC5kaWQ6MTY3RkUyMEFCREQ0RTExMUFFODdDOUNGOURFNjQ5MUYiIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50
    SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6RjYyRDMzNjdFQzRBMTFFMTg2RDRCN0EyNTQxQTE2QkMiIHhtcE1NOkluc3Rh
    bmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6RjYyRDMzNjZFQzRBMTFFMTg2RDRCN0EyNTQxQTE2QkMiIHhtcDpDcmVh
    dG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNSBXaW5kb3dzIj4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9t
    IHN0UmVmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6NDk5QTM0OUY0OUVDRTExMUFEQjdGMjZDRTM5OTI3
    NTkiIHN0UmVmOmRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6MTY3RkUyMEFCREQ0RTExMUFFODdDOUNGOURF
    NjQ5MUYiLz4gPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+IDwvcmRmOlJERj4gPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+IDw/eHBh
    Y2tldCBlbmQ9InIiPz7/7gAOQWRvYmUAZMAAAAAB/9sAhAACAQEBAQECAQECAwIBAgMDAgICAgMD
    AwMDAwMDBAMEBAQEAwQEBQYGBgUEBwcICAcHCgoKCgoMDAwMDAwMDAwMAQICAgQDBAcEBAcKCAcI
    CgwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz/wAARCABN
    ASwDAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAugABAAIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAwIIBQYHCQQBAQACAwEBAQEBAAAAAAAA
    AAACAwEEBgUHCAAJEAABAwMDAwMCAgUIBwkBAAACAQMEAAUGEQcIMRIJIUETFBUiCjK0dXY4UUIj
    tRYXNzmzdNSFlcW2YZEzJCU2J1cYGREAAQIEBAQDBQQIBAcBAAAAAQACEQMEBSExEgZBUXEHYYET
    kbEicjWhcxQ0wdEykrLCIxVCYoKz4VIzU4NUNhb/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AOPF0r7bX81woL0qCiUa
    golCoKJQqCiUF6VCJQLpUIgoF0qEYRlUIgoF1oUYRl0r8iCM6FGEZ+9QjCMulQjCI/ehKMIzqCjC
    IvehKMIy61CYERdKFGER+9CjCI+tQUwIi6UJTAiP3qCjCI/ehKYER0KMIjoSmBCdQmBEdCmBCdCm
    BEfvUFMCJz3oUYQue9CmhEdCjCE6FMCI6EpgQnUJgQl1oSmBHQo1aYulbdeEhQXpUFEo1BRKFQUS
    hUFEoL0qESgXSoRBQLpUIwjKoRBQLrQowjLpX5EEZ0KMIz96hGEZdKhGER+9CUYRnUFGERe9CUYR
    l1qEwIi6UKMIj96FGER9agpgRF0oSmBEfvUFGER+9CUwIjoUYRHQlMCE6hMCI6FMCE6FMCI/eoKY
    ETnvQowhc96FNCI6FGEJ0KYER0JTAhOoTAhLrQlMCOhRq0xdK268JCgvSoKJRqCiUKgolCoKJQXp
    UIlAulQiCgXSoRhGVQiCz+H7Qbtbiwnbnt9i93vttYc+B+RZrbMmtNu9qH2GcZo0QtFRdFXXSqVT
    cJFOQ2bMa0nmQPeV0qO1VVU0ukSnvAwi1pPuClP2P3qtmRwsNuWH3uPl9yFx23Wp+1T25koGRVxw
    mGCZRw0ARVSUUXREXWgbc6ZzDMExha3M6hAR5mMAmus9WyY2U6S8PdGALXRMM4CETDwX3Fxc5M//
    AF1k/wDwC6/7PSP71R/96X+839atDbtw/wDXm/uO/UoFxb5Nev8A8dZP/wAAuv8As9R/eqP/AL0v
    95v60Y27cP8A15v7jv1LRbjAnWqa9a7oy5GuUZw2JEd8CbdadbJQMDA0QhISRUVFTVFroNcHAOaY
    grluYWOLXCBGBB4L5T96/FSF0SzcPOVeSYM7ubZdushf28ZjuXA70lpmDD+labV43xdNsRJsQRVU
    hVU9OtcibfqKXM9F05gfGENQjHlDmtBJ2zcZsk1DKeYZYEdWkwgMYxhl4rmRe9dQrihGXWoTAiLp
    QowiP3oUYRH1qCmBEXShKYF9OPYzkmY3tjGcQt8m65HLJQi2+2sOyZLxCKmqNtMiRkqCKr6J0SlT
    ZrZTS95AA4nAKxIkvnODJbS5xyAESfIJcv29z7Ar6GL5zY7hZcmdAHW7ddoUmJKMHSUQIWZAAaoS
    oqIqJ6qlKlVMuc3XLcHDmCCPaE+dSTZDtE1jmu5EEH2FLnm0G7O2DMeRuVi93x6PMUwiHfLbMgC+
    TaIpo2spptCUUJNdOmtLkVsmfESntdDkQfcn1Fvn00DOluZHLUCI+0LWDp5VcITqEwIjoUwIToUw
    Ij96gpgROe9CjCy2EbZbk7o3B607Z49c8iusdv6mRFsUCVPdaa7kD5DCK24Qj3Eiaqmmq1Wn1MuS
    IzHBo8SB71cpqWbPMJTC4jkCfcsTkFhvmL3mVjuTQn7dkEJwo0yBPZcjyGHQXQm3WnUExJF9FRUR
    UomTGvAc0gg8QofLdLcWvBBGYOBWOOpUhEdCUwITqEwIS60JTAjoUatMXStuvCQoL0qCiWf2r2p3
    B3uz2BthtZbDvGeXP5/oLcwbTZvfTR3JbuhPm2CdrTRF6knT+WqVwr5NFJM+e7SxsInqYDLxK6Nr
    tVRcp7aalZrmOjACGMASc4DIErpWS+ODm/iVytNnvm3VyC6XyStvtjEc4kknnhaN8kVIz7nYItgp
    EZ6CiJ6qlcSTvO1zWucye2DRE5jDLiBHHgMVp6jt3epDmMfTPi8waBAxMI8CYCAiSYAc1928fjA5
    u7FYM9uPn2FOJiERtX7hJtc2BcShtiPcRvtwX3XBAURVI0FRTT1VKRbt8WyumiTKm/EcgQWx6EgD
    yzVm79tL1bZBqJ8g6AIktLXQ6hpJhzOQ5qW0niz5zb2YWxuBheEON4rNbGRb37vMgW05TZp3CbTM
    19p1QJNFElFBJFRUVUobhvm10c0yZk34hnAF0OpAI8s0y09sr3cJIqJMg6CIguLWxHMBxBhyMIHg
    tOt/B7lbdt5J/HyJhcxN47dFK6SbG+7EYdWGJg2r7LjzwNOt9ziaE0ZIvrp0XS+/c9A2mFWZo9Jx
    gHYnHkYCIPUBcyVsy6PrHUAkO9Zo1FpIBhzBJgRjmCV+71cFOWnHjDP7wt5cLl2PDPqGoKz3noTw
    C+8hK2JJGfdJNexfVU019NdVSgt26KCvmejTTQ50IwgRgOoCO77Kulrk+vVyCxkQIxBxOWRKx2xf
    DjkxyatM++7F4lJyGz2x4Ik6RGdiMg084HyCGsp5rVe319NdPfrTLpuGitzg2qmBhcIjPLyBS7Jt
    O43djn0UkzGtMCQQIHzIXp34GsLybbjZncvAc0i/RZdZswettzhK406UeVHtsRp1oiZIwUgJFRdF
    XRUrxXuhUsqKiRNlmLXSog8wSYHFfRvZSjmUtJUyJwg9k4gjAwIa2IwwwXy+QXe/bvjj5QdiN5t1
    5bkHALNY8j+vlMMPSTD6uDPgtaNMCZlq6+KeiemuvSp2pbZ1fZaunkCL3PZARhkWk4nwCHfF4kWv
    cdBV1JhLZLmRMCcw5owGOZCtPxh5h7D8wbHdMi2Iub1ztVmfbhTzkw5UNQdebV0EQZTYKWop1SsT
    etv1Vqc1lU0NLhEYg+5ekbd3VRXtjplE4uDDAxBGJ6rB8nPITxd4gZZb8K32vMm25Dc4n3WG1Gt0
    2YJR/mNjuU4rRii97apoq61Ys21a26SzMpmgtaYHEDHPiVU3Bve3WWa2TWPLXOERBpOEYcB4LwN3
    4ymzZzvdmWbY44ruPXi+3a6wHTAmyOPLnvPtEoGiEKqBouipqlfTttkOk00qW/NrGg9QACvjS71D
    KisnTpeLXPcR0LiQuzeM7htuHyW5C4tlgYyd82KsN+gf2vkq5F+naabVJfxPtPOCZg4gIhIIrqiq
    lZ3eF/lUFLMZr0zXMOnOPKIPgtbsHa8+6VsqZ6euQyY3WcIAZwIJiQei9FvLVnPkasyScT4q482/
    xyPFpr+Z3oWrY65/TfWMzGP/ADzqGAtQ2xNFbDX8fXVNE8n2RTWl8H1r4TvUGgY+EDhzOGPJe5dx
    6u+MjLt0uNP6R1ug3jqDhiYiDQDgOK8hth+Mu/fJ/J3MQ2FxeZkl7ZQTk/Ri23HjCaqIlIkyDaYZ
    QlRdFcMda9xud3prez1Kl4YPHM9AMT5BfN9nsNZdJnp0csvIzhkOpMAPMhdN3r8T3PTYbEZGfZtg
    rz+IQ2zkTpljlwbosVptFM3HmYLzrwgIopEfZ2inqqpXGoN622seJUubBxyBBEehIh5ZrRXPt5d6
    CUZ02SSwZlpDoeJAJMPGEFW7tI1QRTUlXRETqq1qCscFZXbLw9+Q3dnEm81x7b96FZJAC7EG/Trd
    a5L4kPcijGnSGnhRU00UwFF19FX10yNZvi2Uz/TdNiRnAEgeYEPYt1QdubxVyxNZIIBy1FrSfIkH
    2gLiG+GwG8/G/NC2+3yxyZjWWiHzhFuDaILzSkoI6w62ptOt9wqne2RDqipr6V3aC5SK6X6tO8Pb
    4fpGYPgVnLnaKm3TPRqpZY7kePiDkR4jBNsBxm325T5ou3+wWNysjydtv6iQ3FVppmMz3IHySJEk
    2mWh7l0RTNEVfRPWl3O609BL9SpeGt9/QDE+SfaLLVXOb6NJLL3eGQHiTADzKt/wd8e/Lfhz5Fdn
    7/v1ijltxafc5saNd4cmJPhK+tlnkjJvQnXUbNUFVQT7VVEXTXRaw+4Ny0VytlQ2nfFwAwIIP7Qx
    gc/Jei7Y2lcLRd6Z9VL0tLiAQQRHS7CIJgeq/fPH/mcY1+xMc/rOZQ9vvpT/AJne4JvdD61L+Rn8
    RVpPPRxv3k5VXDZfaLY2zOXrNJU7InybEgaZjR249uRyRIedUQbbDuTUiX1VURNSVEXI9vrnIoBU
    Tqh2loDfM/FgBxK3Pc+0VFyNLIpm6nEv6AQbiTwC87OVHiA5s8SNvnN1dwbLDuu38VEK53LGZazx
    t4kXahSWybZdENepoKgnuqV6Pat5UNwmelLcQ45BwhHpw8s15TethXG1yvXmtDmDMtMYdcj55KtW
    LYllGeZJCw7CbdJu+WXF0YsC221lyRJkPH+iDTTSERKv8iJWlnTmSml7yA0Zk4ALK08h854lywXO
    OAAxJ8laOxeC/wAm2Q2JL6G3zcNHBVxqHcL3YmJRj2oSatlN/Aq66aOKKovVErJTN92tjtPqx6Nd
    D3e5beT25u726vRh4FzQff71Xbf3jnvhxgzo9td/Mal4zmQgkgIs8QIH2SVRR2O+wTjLzfcip3tm
    Q6oqa6otaCguUitl+rTvDm+H6RmPNZu42qot8z0qlhY7x94ORHiF9fHPiTyN5c5S/h/HbE5mTXeI
    IOTnI3xMxIguKqAsmXLNmO13dq9qGaKWi6a6LSbldqagaH1Dw0HLmegGJT7VZaq4v0UssvIz5DqT
    ADzK6FyM8TXPni9hr+426mBPpgERtX513ssuDdWIYCuhHJG3vPONAKaKpmCB6/pddObb910Fa/05
    Uz4jkCCI9IjHpmuxctm3GgZ6s6UdIzIIMOsCSOuSs5+WI/iy3B/dJf64g1mO5f5SX8/6Ctd2p/OT
    fu/5gqgeT/8AzDd5v3tvX64danbX0+R8g9yyO6fqVR9473rDZ3wA5hbZ7IMcjtxcHlWLZmUzGkxr
    zdpECJ8oTVT6dAjPyBkqTiEiiKN9yp66aetHJvtJOnfh5cwOeI4CJyzxhD7UM7b1ZIkCpmSy2WYY
    kgZ5YRjj0XGDrqlckITqEwIS60JTAjoUatMXStuvCQoL0qCiVl/Dx/mNbdf7/wD+mLnWI7jfRp/+
    j+Nq9L7Q/wD0VN/5P9p69S/JFyty3hrxzXeLArXBumYHcollhheReOK0koXXTcMY7jLhfhYVNEMf
    VUXX00XwjZlhl3is/DTXFrdJcYQjhDmCOPIr6f7i7pm7ft34yQxrn6w0aowEYknAg8OYXRuPG5h7
    /cesS3WvkBqM9lVmh3SbbhX5WAKXGE3Wk+RPxBqSond7da494ovwFZNp2kn03kA8cDgeq0W37l/d
    LfJqntA9VgcRmMRiOir1wR8jGe8teUu4+y96sVvteBYuEmRYH4aSEnqzFuQ2/tlk4840RGhoX9GA
    IPT8XWtdunZ0q1UMipa9znvhqjCGLY4YR9pMfBYHZHcGffLnU0b5bWy5US0iOqAdp+LEgxzwAhli
    sD5Ut4YPGHkVx85GiPxFbrpeLTfX2h1N6xywgty2iQU1PsbcM20XoXqnWrOxbcblR1tHza0t8HDV
    A+ZgD4Kn3NuzbPcLdcMtL3tcebDp1DxgCSPFd/5ubOROS/EDNttbUoS5d1tLk6yONaPC5Nh9txhK
    Chrqhusgmo6+i+mvSsntq4m3XCVOdhpdA9DgfsJW73jaRd7VPp24lzIt44j4mw6kBcP4XwLX4+/E
    /wD3u5MwLWQHape4E5h4fjV+fdABLbHNP0kIm/pmV19UX+Tomm3G519v34dh+HUJY8A39o+3UVjd
    oS27Z2x+KmCDtBmnxc79geY0tWp/l/r1dck2C3DyK+vlJvc/LXpsyS76m6+/bYrrhlpp6kRKq1d7
    qy2y6qSxogBLgOgJXN7HTnTaGomPMXOnEk8yWgkrh35iv/G7bv8AYcz9fWtJ2k/LTvnHuWR77fnK
    f7s/xLp/5dH/AAe3I/bNv/Ujri92/wAxI+U+9aPsR+Vqfnb7lxv8xR/Ezg/7r/8ANZld7tP+Tm/e
    fyhZnvl9QkfdfzOXnqXSvU14oFanxHci96duOWWGbNYTfnYG2eWX2MmRWptqMQTUFkwTvNxonE0R
    P5pJWH31aaefQzaiYyL2MOk44fbBekdtL5V0txk0sp5bLmPGoQGOHSPsVkPOpzG5LbJ8hrfsttbl
    ci0bYX/C2HrxaGWIbjck51yu8GQpG+w44new0IL2knonp61kO3FhpKuldUTpYc9s0wMThANIyPMr
    fd29z19DWtpaeaWy3yRqEBjFzwcxHEABd92344b88dfFhZNtuENvjf8A6QyeBbrpdrqciNGNqXd2
    AkzpYvS3BAjZaVGGV19NBJE9KzNXdqauvLptxJ9FhIAgTg0wAgOZxPmFsqGx1lt2+yRamj8RMa0k
    xAxcIuMTxA+EeRWC8Z+1Plk2a3fmWfl/MkZDsZd4j6vyb7kMW9SoE9v+kYOORSHn0A/xNkCfh9UX
    RO2rG7q2yVUgOoQGzWkZNLQRxjgB4xzVXYtv3FRVJbciXyXA4ueHkHhDEmByIy9i5psL49tr7R5t
    M3jfb2F2qw+CxuLZLSSIrLdxuv06x20aQtEbYkOvuAnQewE00rqXLc85235RifUeSwnwbGPmRAHq
    VxbRs6QzdE4aR6UtomNHDU6EBDkCXEdAs7zr2Y81m8HJe55Rx3uMvHNlLW6EXFoVkyeFbG5DDIpr
    JmMDKD5TdcUi7XhXQdB09Kq7dr7BTUjWVQD5h/aJYTDwBhhDw6q9uq2bnrK50yjcWSWmDQ2YGxA4
    kRxiefDBbL5Q9jc73v8AFKzuJyTtUWDykwKJCvst2CcdwAlDJag3AQcjkofHIYJXVAVVEJB9PwpV
    PaVwl0t5MqkcTImEgRjlCLc+IOEeUeav75tc2tsAnVrQKiUA4whnEB2WECMYc4clifH2dj4CeGi6
    8qrVb2ZW4d2g3DMJPypqMiUcs7ZaWXSBRL4RH4lIUXVFI9PVaduXVd762jJgxpDeghFx65+wJO0d
    Ni246va0F7gXnxMdLAfDL2lcQ8WHlk5Yb280LJspyKvDOV4HmLswY7Ui329g7TPjRH58d6KURhle
    3uYRtRJVREXuTRU9e7u/Z1HS0Lp9K3Q5kOJMQSAQYk84rN7F37X1tyZTVjhMZMjwA0kAkEQA5Q+1
    aT54/wDM4xr9iY5/Wcyrvb76U/5ne4Kj3Q+tS/kZ/EVcXzw8x93+KOyGJ2rY6eVizjL58yG9kUUW
    1lxbfCZaefZjmYkrZPOOtKpj6ogLp6qipiO39kk1895qBqawA6eBJjAnnDH2r0PubuCotlNLbTHS
    +YSNQzAEIgcomGPgtX8FXMndLmZtZuJsTyannlzliCJ8Nwu6I6/Mtd6blx5ESU5oiuIKseinqSoa
    oq6Imlrf1klW2dKqKUaNUcBwLYEEcs/sVPtpuCfdpE6mrD6mmGJzLXRBB55faqM8Kt1ct8f3kPzj
    B9pNsT3W3Nt90veA2O3R3pDc6O1BurkeQ9HViPL0I2o+huKOgh3ar2qWu6vlIy7W6XMnTvRYWteT
    wxERHEc8ua8727Wvst1my5Ej13hzmAYxEHQJEAeAxPAeCsIPG/8AMV7i7jHvouTT8YuEmStyiYzI
    yyI1bIzRuE43HW1Rn34agIqg9roKWn6X4tazhuW3JMr0NAcAIatBifHUQD7PJasWndU+b+J1lhJi
    G6xAeGkEj2jrit6/Mu47Gl8Y9rsyvsVoc5i35y3G+yno2Ey0uvyWgJdS7FdigqevtXO7aTCKqcxp
    +Etj7Dh711e7EoGkkTHD4g+HtbE/aAtqyu+//wAkPCdZ8i2XZYib1X+FZzcu6tNOEWQZG0EqTKNH
    EMXVjMd4MoSKmjYappqlVJTP79e3NnRMtpOH+VuAHhE59Sr02Z/+csDXSICY4Nx/zOxJ8YCMOgVN
    OA3nO3a2TyTJLPzWuV63R2bvdvdaZtr6Qp0ti4G62OnfPcZT6ZxgnRcbUlTXt0H9LXYX/Y8qpa00
    QbKe054gQ8uMYQKxG2+4E6lc9teXTpbhlgTHzhgRGI6LoX5cifiV153buXTAYjtvwSTYZr9lgSyE
    340BzIYpxmXCFVRTBpRElReqVze4bXtoZImGLg4RPM6TFdXti5jrhPMsQaWmA5DUID2LtfHvw9tb
    y+RbdTmRyjtYO7Ps5fepOF4vOHVLzIauJiM6Y0SaLEAgX42y/wDGL1X+jTRziV+7fw9vk0dMfj0N
    1OHDDIePM8OuWgtuzPxNynVtWP6fqO0tP+IxzPhyHHpnRrzo8s+QG9nMjIdj9zYxWDbvbqa9asdx
    ph10o7raiht3V3uQEN2UwYmC9qIDZIKfziLZ7KtcinpGzpZ1OmCJP8vQH2nFYffd3qKmtdImjS2W
    YBvD5upGPgMOtIzrXlYsITqEwIS60JTAjoUatMXStuvCQoL0qCiVl/Dx/mNbdf7/AP8Api51iO43
    0af/AKP42r0vtD/9FTf+T/aer7+eH+CGN+8tr/VZteS9q/qh+7d72r3jvl9FH3rfc5dx8fX8EG1X
    7s2r9VCsxu76pU/eO962uwvotJ9033Ki3hS/jy3g/wBRuf8A1CzXqHcv6VTdW/wFeKdnPrlb8rv9
    wLZ/zFP/ALI2t/16+f6CDVDtB/1ajo33uXV7/f8ARpPmf7mqwHiB5FryB4XWKLdpPz5rhpLiN17y
    UnSCGAlCdLuRFXuim2Pd66kJeuuumT7g2f8AAXJ5aIMmfGPPMe2PkQt12pv/APc7PLDzF8n4Hc8P
    2T+7DHiQVw78wTyCHGdqcU402N7suGRyVyG8tNroo263L8cZsx1/Rdkmpp6dWf8Av03ai0+pPmVr
    hgwaR1OfsGH+pY/vnffRppVuYcZh1O+VuQ6F2P8ApWS/Lx/w05v+8/8AyqHSO7X5yV93/MVZ7EfT
    p/3v8rVxj8xX/jdt3+w5n6+taDtJ+WnfOPcsr32/OU/3Z/iXT/y6P+D25H7Zt/6kdcXu3+YkfKfe
    tH2I/K1Pzt9y43+Yo/iZwf8Adf8A5rMrvdp/yc37z+ULM98vqEj7r+Zy89S6V6mvFAu6eMT/ADAN
    qv26x/o3KzG8vpdR8hWz7f8A1ml+cLvP5ij+NbF/3Itv9fXusv2r+nTPvT/CxbXvZ9Vl/ct/jmK1
    Oet5t5DvEDjkvjDcz/vgskOznIt9tmLEkHc7HHSHPgKYGCgRgRONCSohIodEJFrFU3p2S+vFY3+m
    4uxIiIOMWu/QeWK9Eq/V3HtqWaB39VgbEAwOpgg5vhHEiOeHNUx4g+OXyJcjtzSxnc6bmO223MRu
    SVxyPIhurJC6DS/A3FiTJEQ5Cm6ooqgSCg9y92qIi72+7qtdDJ1yRLmvMINbp84kAww848F5ltrZ
    V6uU/wBOoM6RLEYudqHQAEjVE8sIRxXS/F1uRg/F3yj5hx/yHP8A+21lvcI8NtmaTUJhubd4T7El
    tgFelS9BUkeZDR1UM+3t/SSuPvClmXCzy6lsr0y06iwcGkERyHgThgF39hVsq136bRvn+qHDQHnC
    LgQYYk+IGOJhDNa15O+G3kKsXMLJsq2cgZbku1uXzlvFkk4kd0mMRVloJPRpDcIiSP8AG6pIimiA
    oaKi9USxtK+2x9Cxk8y2PYIHVARhkRHOI84qrvnbV4l3KZMpmzXy5jotLNRAjmCB+zA88ILUuWvj
    53h4u8K7VvnyH3duMTdG/KzBPa6ST8z5npD5ErP1aXNRL4YqI49/QEIl+HVdRVblm3LIr691PS04
    LG4+pgMuMNPE4DHLFUr/ALQqbZbG1VZUuEx+HpGJxJyjq4DE4EA4RyVu+D8KBzx8Jlx42YfMYb3J
    ttuuGIvx3z7BZuEWaVztqu9uhI26Cs6noqa93XtVKxG4HG038VTwdBId5EQd5jH7F6Ltdovm2XUU
    sj1GtLOhB1Nj4HDHryVe/FL4weUez3Mix75cjbEWEYDhsh4AcusmJ8lzuc+O7a4kWIjDjyGiuyUJ
    TT8KomgqqqlaPeG7KSpoXU9K71HPHAHAAxJOXAZLKbE2TXUlxZVVjPSZLPEj4nEFoAhGOJzy5LXP
    PH/mcY1+xMc/rOZVjt99Kf8AM73BV+6H1qX8jP4irg+c3iDurzI2kx4OPbLOQ7jYBNfm3bGIsqOM
    9YN2jCKOg24Y6kixUUQVUUx7u3uVNKxOwrzJts5/4n4WTBAOgYRB/wCPlxXoXcqwT7tIZ+EAe+US
    S0ERg4Z/Zlx4RWveFbh/uB4/tj9yeQ3LKOGJuXhmLLOFPdaV63Wexsy5D0iT8RkIK6UhdAVe5EBN
    UTXSrG+LzLu8+VTUZ16Y4ji50BAdIfaqvbuwTbJTT6uuHp6gDA5hrYkk9Y5Z4LXPy/mUYBvLutyE
    3/lMNf3w5Ffwuxq+IfVx7Xd5c+4KDfXtE31X5OxdFUB16DVjuHKmU0mlpwf6bWw8CWgD3ZdSq/a+
    dKqp9ZVEf1Hvj4hri4/ac+g8FUbf7h75WOVvLK/Y3vva8kDHzu0opuT31JjOG2m0tSSMpUeS8QQU
    jMMJ8gg0XcqJ6IprWuoLxaaCka6nLI6RBohrJhkR+1EnDH3LFXKxXq41z2VLXw1GLjH02tjmD+zA
    DGAx81bj8yA3aw4TbXfYHVk2AciijDkquvyMfYZnxGqogp+IE16JWO7cE/jZ2rA6DH94Ldd1AP7f
    I04jWIfulZze3Frz5SPB9jH9wXZeN0bDDscmRZmjAXnLxjsdIFxhomooLhNm440Kp+NFDT9JFqvR
    TRZL4/8AEYMcXY+DjEHpkDyx5K1XSnX/AG+z8N8T2huH+Zog4dcyOeHNUq4B+ELeLkXPyXIuWUO9
    7R7TWOEbjFzvkD7fLkTRMDJUj3UWiSM2wLhOOqiDr2oir+LTZ3/e0mkDW0hbOe45AxEOo4kwgFhd
    t7Bn1pe6sDpMtozIgSehhgBGJXUfy4luxa0c6t2rTg05y54TFsEyPZ7lIaRl2XBbyCIEd9xtFJAJ
    xtBJR1XRV0rldxHOdQyS8QcXCI5HSYhdrti1jbhPEsxaGGB5jUIH2LC+R/y/b94t5NLaxjXfb9p9
    kcjdiM45HfLsvLrPy2+5SJRJ2opvxnnWW0X0bAvT1IlU9vbTkPtp1YvnNz5cQB0MCeZ8kG5d5VDL
    oA3Bkh8NP/NwcT1BIHIea3n8w1xyxPerZ7AvJdsiAzsZnwoFsyKdGFER613IEk2ec4idFE3VYNVV
    V1Nsf5tUNhXB9PNmW6dgQSQPEftD9PkV0u4ltZUyZVzkYggAnwOLT+jzAXkYdepFeSBCdQmBCXWh
    KYEdCjVpi6Vt14SFBelQUS2TZ7eLcbYLca3btbS3H7TuDafqPt9w+niyvi+qiuw3f6KY080Xc08Y
    /iBdNdU9dFqjcrdJr5LqeobqY6EREjIgjEEHMDiupZ7vUWuobV0jtExkYGAMIgg4EEZEjELfN+fI
    Fy65NYOO3G9+W/e8MCS1chhfa7LD0ksCYNn8kCFHc9EcL07tPXpXIte0bdbZvrUsrS+EI6nHA9XE
    cF375v27XiR+HrZ2tkQYaWDERhi1oPHms1t95TOd+1eD2rbjA86+gwuyRmrba4X2XHn/AIYzAoDY
    fJItzjhaInUiVf5VqpWbFtVVNdOmyYvcYk6niJPR0FfoO518opDKeRUaWMADRolmAGWJYT7StC2V
    5c8huOueXjc7ZzIfs+cX9t1m7TvobbL+cHpAyzT4p0Z9odXRQvwCn8nT0rp3Pb9HcJTZFSzUxmQi
    4QgIZgg5c1xrNuuvtU99TSTNEyZEOOlpjExODgQMeQXZ9mN0N7fK1yfwLjny3zGXcMMcK+PQ5Fqg
    2S3yojrdjkzu4CiwAEkJyE2hIYr+HVE7VXWs1cqGm2vQzqy3ygHfDGJcQfiA4u5E5cea2VnudbvS
    5U9vus5zmfHAtaxpB0F3BuOLRGMcMoZr034c8FtlPHVjmV3vHcmuMiz3gY0u9TsnlQ2ocVm3C+om
    KNMsAGiPl3kSr6adNPXxTcW6Km/vltfLaC2IAaDEkw8THLAL6P2lsqj2rLnPlzXFr4FxeQAA2OOA
    AGZiSvIHyN8mYvK/ltk26FjeN7BWTbseNq4ij/6bAFWgcESXVEecU3tF9U7+iV9AbQsptdBLkOEH
    /tO+Y/qEB5L5X39uIXq6TalhjLHws+VuEfMxd5rD8eeeHK3ijjU7D9gsq+w45cpX3ObG+2Wed8kn
    4gY7++4w5Jp+BsU0FUT06U277Xobm8TKqXrcBAfE4YZ8CFXsO9LnZpbpVDN0NcYkaWHGEP8AE0nI
    LBcjOWO//LG927I+QF/+/wB6tLBwbe99DbYPxMOOfKQ9ttjRhLUvXUkVasWmxUtsa5lIzQHGJxJx
    8yVXvu5q68vbMrpmtzRAYNEBn/hAWR4685eUvEuz3Kwcfco/s/abu83MuLX220TvleaBWwLuuUSS
    Q6CumgqiVXu+2qK5ua+ql6y0QGLh7iFbsO8LjZmOZQzdAcYn4WmJHzNKwfIzlRvzywyeFmO/9++/
    5HbYv2yFJ+it0H443ym/2dltjxgX8bhLqSKvr10p9pslLbGGXSs0tJicSccuJKr3zcdbeZjZtbM1
    uaIAwaMIx/wgDMrnRdK6i44WZ2z3NzjZncC1bpbbTvtud2R8Z1rnfDHkfC+KKiF8Upt1ovRehCqV
    UraOXVSnSZwixwgRiMPKBV+3V82inMqJDtL2GIMAYHoQR7Qs3yM5Pb5csM2i7i7/AN8+/wCYwoLd
    ljTPo7fB7ITL78kGvjtseM2ujklxe5RUvXTXRE0qWqz01tlmVSt0tJjCJOMAOJJyAXQvV/q7vNE+
    tfreG6QYNGAJMINAGZPivp438v8AkXxHyGTkWwOTP2N6agjcInYzJhS0b7kD54soHWSUUJe0u3uH
    VdFSlXexUtyaGVLA6GRyI6EYp9i3LW2d5fRzCyOYwIPUGI88xwXUN5vMTz63rxCTgl9y8LVjU1so
    85vHIUa3PSGjRRICkNCr4iqKqKgGKKnoutcSg2JbKR4mNl6nDLUSYeWX2LR3LuXeK6UZT5ulpwOk
    BpPnn7Cqug87HdCRHJQfAkMDBVEhIV1RUVPVFRa1pEcCsO0kGIVqtv8AzZeRDbvFWsSZzFm8RIwI
    zGl3+2wps0ARFRO6STYuOr6/pOqa/wDbWLqtgWuc/X6ZbHgCQPZw8oL0Oi7n3mnliX6ocBkXNBPt
    zPnFcF5Ccmt9uU+aJn2/WRychyNsFYjFJ+NtiK0pd6txo8cW2WhVfVUAE1X1XVa0NttNPb5fp0zA
    0faepOJ81l7tfKu6TPWq5he7hHIeAAwHkF9fGTmByF4eZe9mewGQu2afMAWLjEJtqTCmtgqqIyI0
    gTbPt7l7S07h1XtVNVpN2slNcmenUs1AZcCOhGKs2PcNZaZhmUj9JOYzB6g4fpHBb/u95Zudu82a
    Y5nOTZikWfiMwbxYIdst8BmDHngBNjJcjGy42+aCSonzIaDqvaiarry6PZ1vpZb5bJcQ8QJJMSOU
    Y4eUF2q/ft0rJkua+bAyzFoAAAPOEIE9Yw4Lle/fKffjk1udG3k3vvv3vciGxGhRrl9FbofYzEdN
    5kfhgR47K9puEuqhquvrrXUt9op6GUZFO3SwkmESc88SSVx7nfKq4zhUVL9TwAIwAwGIwAA+xbhY
    PJbzaxjkHceUFuzqSu8F5YjwbzKONBSHOixGhZZYet7bAROwBD8Pa0ioqqSKhEqrQm7XoH0wpDLH
    ptJIxMQTmQYx+37F1ZO8blLq3Vomn1HAAmAgQMAC2Gn7PHMr6+U3lM5q8vsRTbzd3Ku3b0iFyTZL
    HFYt0WWYGjgLKSOiG8gkKEgmSiioiomqa0m1bTobc/1JLPi5kxI6Ry8sVYvO9bjdJfpT5nwcgAAe
    sM+hwXKtgOR29fFncVjdbYXIJGPZuy2cUpMZG3G347iiRsSGHxcZebVQEuxwVTuRCT1RFTqXG2yK
    6X6NQ0Ob+nmDmD0XJtV2qLdN9emeWO945EHAjwK7FyN8wnPTk5t7L2qz/LW4WA3ECYusDHoMa3LO
    ZJFQmn3mR+YmyRVQm0NAJPQkVK4du2db6KYJstkXDIkkw6DKPjmOC0d033crhKMmbMgw5hoAj4E5
    w8IwPFc/3t8gHLnkTs1ZuP8AvNl33zabHnIT9otj1rszJsO26G5AjH9VFhNSjIWHTBVNxVLVVLVf
    WrtFt+jpJzqiSzS90YmLuJicCYZ+CoV25q6tkNpqiZqlthAQbhAQGIAOR59V8PFfnNyh4WXuVeeP
    GUPWaNcFErna3m2ZdumKCKIk9FlA42pihKiGiISey1N2sdLcWgVDNUMjkR5hTZtw1drcXUry2OYz
    B6g+/NbxyZ8vPPPlXg8jbLcrMEi7eTB+O42nH4ca2NTQXqElyOCPONr7tqfYvuK1z7btGgoX+rKZ
    FwyJJMOnDzzXUum9bjcJfpTZkGHMNAEesMfKMFy3jJzC5GcNMsuOc8bci/s3lN1ifaZ8r6C2XD5Y
    vzBI+PsukWUA/jbFdRFF9OuldG52inuDAypbqAMRiRj5ELm2i9VNteZlK/S4iBwBwz4grS90ty82
    3l3DvW625M37ln2Qy37teJ/wsR/qJUg1ccc+KK200GpLroAoieyVZpqZlPLbKliDWiAHh54qtU1U
    ypmOnTTFzjEnARJ6YLpto8j3M+wcaXeH0HM/k45vQ5NoPHJtpscxEiS3TfcbGXLguyx0ccUgUXUV
    tdOxR0TTlP29RuqfxZZ/ViDEFwxHgDDrhjxXZlblrWUv4MTP6UCIENOB8SI9McOC4UddgrjBCdQm
    BCXWhKYEdCjVpi6Vt14SFBelQUSjUFEoVBRKFQUSgvSoRJ7Nfb3jVzavmOTH7feo6qTEyE64w+2p
    CoKoONKJJqiqnovSlzZTZjS14BB4HEJ8ie+S4PluLXDIgwI8wsvl+8u7+e29LVnWV3i9WtF7kjXa
    5zZjSLqha9kh0x6ii9Paqsi3U8g6pUtrTzDQPcFeqbvV1LdM+c945OcSPtK1cqtqiFAutCjCMulf
    kQRnQowjP3qEYRl0qEYRH70JRhGdQUYRF70JRhGXWoTAiLpQowiP3oUYRH1qCmBEXShKYER+9QUY
    RH70JTAiOhRhEdCUwITqEwIjoUwIToUwIj96gpgROe9CjCFz3oU0IjoUYQnQpgRHQlMCE6hMCEut
    CUwI6FGrTF0rbrwkKC9KgolGoKJQqCiUKgolBelQiUC6VCIKBdKhGEZVCIKBdaFGEZdK/IgjOhRh
    GfvUIwjLpUIwiP3oSjCM6gowiL3oSjCMutQmBEXShRhEfvQowiPrUFMCIulCUwIj96gowiP3oSmB
    EdCjCI6EpgQnUJgRHQpgQnQpgRH71BTAic96FGELnvQpoRHQowhOhTAiOhKYEJ1CYEJdaEpgR0KN
    WmLpW3XhIUF6VBRKNQUShUFEoVBRKC9KhEoF0qEQUC6VCMIyqEQUC60KMIy6V+RBGdCjCM/eoRhG
    XSoRhEfvQlGEZ1BRhEXvQlGEZdahMCIulCjCI/ehRhEfWoKYERdKEpgRH71BRhEfvQlMCI6FGER0
    JTAhOoTAiOhTAhOhTAiP3qCmBE570KMIXPehTQiOhRhCdCmBEdCUwITqEwIS60JTAjoUa//Z"
    />
```

Comment: Maybe your email client doesn't support data uris. Which client are you using? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070196/what-is-data-uri-support-like-in-major-email-client-software for a list of clients that support data uris.

Comment: Outlook doesn't support data uris, is there any way you could host this image?

Comment: I have had a look at some emails and I have noticed they are stored as `email.mht` which is using the Base64 stuff do I need to do something like that for this to work?

I can host images but because of the way the network can work in my company some people might not be able to load the images. If push comes to shove I will use hosted images but at the min I am trying to get the widest range.

Comment: try using a [hidden attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786644/net-embedding-attached-image-in-html-email)

Comment: Top banana!! That worked thanks :D Add it as an Answer and I will give yo ua tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a hidden attachment as per [.net - embedding attached image in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786644/net-embedding-attached-image-in-html-email)

```
Dim plainView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", Nothing, "text/plain")

Dim logo As New LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("images1/links/beach-icon.jpg"))

logo.ContentId = "embeddedimage"

Dim htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<p>Here is an embedded image.</p> <img src=cid:embeddedimage> <p>More text here</p>", Nothing, "text/html")

htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo)

objMM.AlternateViews.Add(plainView)
objMM.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
```